How to make the screen wake up with Notifee?
How can I make the screen wake up (even if it is locked), when a Notifee message appears?
I thought that when a message appears in background state, it will make the screen wake up, but it remains sleeping.
This is my attempt and config:
// Display a notification
  await notifee.displayNotification({
    id: 'default',
    title: notification.message?.title,
    body: notification.message?.body,
    android: {
      category: AndroidCategory.CALL,
      vibrationPattern: [300, 500],
      lights: ['red', 300, 600],
      channelId,
      smallIcon: 'ic_launcher', // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
      pressAction: {
        id: 'default',
        launchActivity: 'default',
        // launchActivity: 'com.awesome.app.CustomActivity',
      },

      fullScreenAction: {
        id: 'full-screen',
        mainComponent: 'custom-component',
        // For Android Activity other than the default:
        launchActivity: 'com.awesome.app.FullScreenActivity',
      },
      // asForegroundService: true,
      actions: [
        {
          title: 'Answer',
          pressAction: {id: 'answer', launchActivity: 'default'},
        },
        {
          title: 'Cancel',
          pressAction: {
            id: 'decline',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });

